Attempting to transition from loader animation to personal website but only the loader animation displays
The whole point of it, is to showcase a black background screen with a moving animation for 5-6 seconds, and then it fades into displaying my personal webpage. but it is just stuck on the loading animation.



$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Set a timeout to hide the preloader
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.loader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            // This callback is executed once the fadeOut completes
            $('.main-content').fadeIn('slow'); // Make sure this class matches your main content wrapper
        });
    }, 2000); // The loader will fade out after 2 seconds
});
/* Loader Styles */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
  }
  
  .loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-out; /* Transition duration changed to 2s */
  }
  
  
  /*
  .loader:hover {
    background: #03e9f4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4, 0 0 200px #03e9f4;
  }
  */
  
  .loader span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .loader span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: animate1 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate1 {
    0% {
      left: -100%;
    }
    100% {
      left: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .loader span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: animate3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate3 {
    0% {
      left: 100%;
    }
    100% {
      left: -100%;
    }
  }
  
  .loader span:nth-child(2) {
    right: 0;
    top: -100%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: animate2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate2 {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    100% {
      top: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .loader span:nth-child(4) {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: animate4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
  }
  
  @keyframes animate4 {
    0% {
      top: 100%;
    }
    100% {
      top: -100%;
    }
  }
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kabir's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>



i tried to put the jquery above html but it didn't do much, i am not sure if it is cause of the local host either.
